# Signup with Facebook JS SDK

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I'm trying to create a signup functionality with Facebook JS SDK, But i got different type of records, than i search a lot and come to know that Facebook update his app policy's, they release v2.0 for apps.

Now it sending different response on login

```
Object {authResponse: Object, status: "connected"}
authResponse: Object
accessToken: "CAATZCeMqNYsABADVG3lHL1WYJiwnZASJIBzUtkfB4MFyFUC21g6myDeAP6WDSKkd8ZAnggffW5sIJzSDqmqxxvRgdeT7MKRXJ0L8Logg57PYwawEBSbgqz9I5qGU9Oo7uvaRN5MupjCfvo5w4bfCDZA5uvMkg7AK8DbwhXW4WoGHZBgG6EsmDDWZCnbVpUxWUZD"
expiresIn: 4562
signedRequest: "GXGqWXN9C5IzSy6jf2NOOQK7-ZK9JisKBCLEBHbaoIc.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"
userID: "100000015593107"
__proto__: Object
status: "connected"
__proto__: Object
}
```

as in last SDK we get email using

> response.email

but in new one we got only userID which is also app specific and

> response.authResponse.signedRequest

So i search how we can extract the "signedRequest" because i think the rest value surely encrypted in this code ..

So i used

```
$signed_request= $_POST['maindata'];
        if (isset($signed_request))
        {
            $data_signed_request = explode('.', $signed_request); // Get the part of the signed_request we need.
            $jsonData = base64_decode($data_signed_request['1']); // Base64 Decode signed_request making it JSON.
            $objData = json_decode($jsonData, true); // Split the JSON into arrays.
        }
        print_r($objData);
```

but its again send me

```
Array
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [code] => AQA9smFIfuuz12zo5Ut0gXasWrR5nRWexu4IFXqE0xgP37OJRqBrh8YxJ6akyhyIau3su2ShaeW3S8uhtaybF_swik_Je_P4pjYNy_H_RiLK6efJ6ZDL490-NULJK3xIl6Bk_UrDGfkTMnWXZdV7-M6c_q24pZ2T8J6jpzv3FCFtaK9mn_1Uhm8rr4eViP9UmUSLep9585_VaHx6bE2LAA1Iw9G_ArgobQJWPhDWs9SH7N73sKWejD703lNhinXcmKtEu56joNuL88o0OYQumTA_o1xHBybwRl58zEkXJLuU-TV_z69QoJzALxTBzCAPpWpD-W52TyJwKI60LMNPn84l
    [issued_at] => 1399275838
    [user_id] => 100000015593107
)
```

I'm wondering how we can get the email address , Please if you have some idea please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use the acquired `access_token` and use the Facebook API endpoint `GET /me` and pass the `access_token` the response of the said endpoint will allow you to obtain the email address given that the email address being associated to the Facebook is account is still valid.